# 'System.Runtime.InteropServices.ExternalException'

Tags: c#, runtime-error, image-resizing

I keep getting this error of 'System.Runtime.InteropServices.ExternalException' on line 70 "img3.Save(finalImage, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg);". Originally I had a program that stitched two photos together that worked fine, but I wanted the two images to be the same size (300 pixles by 300 pixles) so I inserted a method:

```
public static Image resizeImage(Image imgToResize, Size size)
{
    return (Image)(new Bitmap(imgToResize, size));
}
```

and in my CombineImages method put:

```
img = resizeImage(img, new Size(300, 300));
```

but now I am getting an error. Here is my code:

```
    private void cmdCombine_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //Change the path to location where your images are stored.
        DirectoryInfo directory = new DirectoryInfo(@"C:\Users\Elder Zollinger\Desktop\Images");
        if (directory != null)
        {
            FileInfo[] files = directory.GetFiles();
            CombineImages(files);
        }

    }
    private void CombineImages(FileInfo[] files)
    {
        //change the location to store the final image.
        string finalImage = @"C:\Users\Elder Zollinger\Desktop\Images\Final.jpg";
        List<int> imageHeights = new List<int>();
        int nIndex = 0;
        int width = 0;
        foreach (FileInfo file in files)
        {
            Image img = Image.FromFile(file.FullName);
            img = resizeImage(img, new Size(300, 300));
            imageHeights.Add(img.Height);
            width += img.Width;
            img.Dispose();
        }
        imageHeights.Sort();
        int height = imageHeights[imageHeights.Count - 1];
        Bitmap img3 = new Bitmap(width, height);
        Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(img3);
        g.Clear(SystemColors.AppWorkspace);
        foreach (FileInfo file in files)
        {
            Image img = Image.FromFile(file.FullName);
            if (nIndex == 0)
            {
                g.DrawImage(img, new Point(0, 0));
                nIndex++;
                width = img.Width;
            }
            else
            {
                g.DrawImage(img, new Point(width, 0));
                width += img.Width;
            }
            img.Dispose();
        }
        g.Dispose();
        img3.Save(finalImage, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg);
        img3.Dispose();
        imageLocation.Image = Image.FromFile(finalImage);
    }
    public static Image resizeImage(Image imgToResize, Size size)
    {
        return (Image)(new Bitmap(imgToResize, size));
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Is there an inner exception and/or message you can include?

Comment: An unhandled exception of type 'System.Runtime.InteropServices.ExternalException' occurred in System.Drawing.dll

Additional information: A generic error occurred in GDI+.

Answer (score 1):

It is likely that the image format of the uploaded image cannot be converted directly to Jpeg.  One thing we do when resizing is actually draw the image to a new `Graphics` instance as follows.  Note that the first 2 lines attempt to get the pixel and image formats directly from the original image instance - you may have issues with CMYK and images with a transparency layer (GIF/PNG).

```
            var pixelFormat = imgToResize.PixelFormat;
            var imageFormat = imgToResize.RawFormat;

            Bitmap b = new Bitmap(newWidth.Value, newHeight.Value, pixelFormat);
            Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(b);

            g.SmoothingMode = SmoothingMode.AntiAlias;
            g.InterpolationMode = InterpolationMode.HighQualityBicubic;
            g.PixelOffsetMode = PixelOffsetMode.HighQuality;

            g.DrawImage(imgToResize, (float)-0.5, (float)-0.5, newWidth.Value + 1, newHeight.Value + 1);
            g.Dispose();

            b.Save(stream, imageFormat);
```